# Unity Animation keeps looping even while Loop time is unchecked

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to fix this?????
The animation just keeps looping even when the Loop time is unchecked, any answers.
I even tried reimporting it but it didn't work either.

Comment: Do you have a script that is running the animation? If so, could you please provide the script?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that, if you have a FBX Animation File, to click the "Apply" button, down here, after setting it off.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwfUp.png

Comment: Thank you a lot!!!!!!!! OMG I am blind, I didn't see that tiny button, thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with an .anim file. In my case I had to uncheck *"Can transition to self"* on the transition settings.